What to do, given mTLS with HTTP Version 2 is not available in Azure App Service?
At the time of writing, the Azure documentation clearly shows a screenshot where client certificates are required on an App Service and the HTTP version is set to 2.0. However, this no longer appears to be possible - the Azure console now states that client certificates can only be evaluated if HTTP 1.1 is selected.
Here is the screenshot from the Azure documentation:

Here is a screenshot from the actual Azure console:

As the majority of our clients are already connecting using HTTP 2.0, I'm wondering, in order to introduce optional mTLS support, do I have to create a new subdomain and new proxy App Service with HTTP 1.1 configured, then ask/redirect our clients to use the proxy subdomain? Why exactly is 2.0 with mTLS not supported? What is the best approach from here?

What exactly did Azure console say and under what context? You should edit the question to include at least the exact text, or a clear screenshot.

I've added a screenshot from the Azure console

Don't you also need to enable end-to-end TLS Encryption?

I could be wrong, but I don't believe end-to-end TLS encryption is necessary. I do want to have the client's certificate passed to the application but that can occur regardless of end-to-end encryption being enabled or disabled.


HTTP/2 protocol negotiation happens before the TLS handshake completes
This means client certificates cannot be properly evaluated when using HTTP/2
This is a protocol-level constraint, not just an Azure limitation

Create a TLS-terminating Proxy.
nginx.conf:
http {
    upstream backend {
        server your-main-app.azurewebsites.net:443;
        keepalive 32;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mtls.yourdomain.com;

        # SSL configuration
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

        # Client certificate verification
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ca.crt;
        ssl_verify_client optional; # or 'on' for required

        # Proxy to main application
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            
            # Pass client certificate information
            proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-Cert $ssl_client_cert;
            proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-Verify $ssl_client_verify;
            proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
        }
    }
}

Split Traffic approach: create a new HTTP/1.1 endpoint specifically for clients requiring mTLS, Keep the existing HTTP/2 endpoint for regular traffic.
Use Azure Front Door or load balancer to route based on hostname
Reference:

Configure TLS mutual authentication - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn

Mutual TLS or Client Certificate Auth with Azure

How to enable HTTP/2 on an Azure App Service web app


